# List hide after move anchor from :hover element

Tags: html, css

I want to show list when hover over `<a>` element. The list is shown but when I want to choose an item from it, it hides again.

I need code to stay showing until i click on item in it.

I want something in CSS please, I am learning JS now

```css
.acc {
  /* Account id */
  font-family: 'Courier', arial;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.acc:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.acc:hover+.hide {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Courier', arial;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="acc" href="acc">Accounts </a>
  <ul class="hide">
    <li><a href="face">Facebook</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working as expected. Clicking on "Accounts" will lead to another page you have linked to. So it looks like it has disappeared.

Comment: I made a snippet for you. Please also take care in your punctuation. It is very straight forward: Space AFTER punctuation and first person pronoun is capital **I**

Comment: Perhaps something here: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+list++hover+allow+select+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Of course the list hides again when you move over it - because then the link before it is _not_ hovered any more. If there is not spacing whatsoever between the two elements (so that the mouse cursor can _seamlessly_ move from one to the other) then you can fix this, by adding the additional selector `.hide:hover` to your rule. If not, then you would need to use `:hover` on a common _ancestor_ element of the link and the list, to trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add .hide:hover.

```
.acc:hover + .hide,
.hide:hover{
    display:block;
    font-family:'Courier', arial;
    color:black;
    font-size:3em;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```